# Cannot enable Cortana in India

Tags: 8.1, cortana

I have been trying to make Cortana work on my Lumia 520. I have followed the [guidelines](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortana-alpha) provided by Microsoft:

- I have updated the phone to **Windows Phone 8.1**
- Language is set to **English (India)**
- Region is set to **India** and regional format is "match phone language"
- Finally, speech is set to **English (United Kingdom)**

I restarted the phone but when I press the search button for a while, it still opens the old Bing app. If I search "Cortana Settings", the Cortana settings page appears, but Cortana is off and I cannot turn it on. It says "**Not available in this region**".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I upgraded my Lumia 540 onto w10 that time I had to set up Cortana in uk language but after hard resetting my phone i setes up Cortana in India eng and it's working so thanks to microsoft

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to have Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 to try Cortana *alpha* which is released for India, Canada, and Australia region. Check your phone OS version from **settings** >> **about** and try to get an update from **settings** >> **phone update** if required.

For setting up additional Cortana settings (language, country/region, speech) please follow this [wpcentral forum link](http://www.wpcentral.com/comment/1171299) .

Comment: I have clearly specified in my question that my phone is updated to **8.1 (cyan)**. And the link you have provided is same as the steps i have specified.

Comment: @smashIT 8.1 Update 1 comes after the Cyan update in the Denim update for Lumia phones

Comment: @RowlandShaw I thought update 8.1 is same as 8.1 1 update. [Take a look](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-update-1)

Comment: @smashIT That link has a distinction between 8.1 Update 1 and 8.1 (albeit not with the best wording)

Comment: @RowlandShaw  I have updated to the recent 8.1 1 update. Still no Luck..

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to update to windows 8.1 update 1. Then your settings should be 
Region - India 
Language- English (India)
Speech language - English(UK)

When your phone is set to the correct language, region, and Speech language, go to Cortana by pressing the Search button. You’ll see two Cortana acknowledgement screens, where you’ll need to review the info and accept the conditions for using the Cortana alpha version

Answer (score 1):

You can activate Cortana even if you reside in India on your Windows Phone 8.1 device.

Here are the steps:

Go to App list > Settings > Speech Language.

download English (United Kingdom) language pack. Just tap on the English (United Kingdom) and you will see the sub-text "Downloading language".

Downloading and installing it is easy. Just follow the onscreen commands. Your phone will restart, and gears will appear for sometime on your phone. Make sure your phone do not turns off due to low battery while you Windows Phone is getting updated.

For using Cortana, you will need to have a Windows Live account. If you don't have one, Sign Up for Windows account.

[How to activate Cortana in India - Windows Phone 8.1](http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2015/07/how-to-activate-cortana-in-india.html)

Answer (score 0):

Language must be  set to English (United Kingdom) instead of English (India).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use a Windows phone anymore :D